# How to fix a "not defined" error in a function

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm creating a function as part of a GRU exercise to learn more about python and GRU.  I seem to be running into a name error.

I've reviewed a number of articles about defining items in python, but I thought I had this clearly defined with the code following it.

```
    def workflow(EV_data, get_split, train_model, get_rmse,n_train = 250,n_test = 50,look_back = 1):
    gX_train, gY_train, gX_test, gY_test, scaler, start_point = get_split(EV_data, n_train, n_test)

    model = train_model(gX_train, gY_train, gX_test, gY_test)

    RMSE, predictions = get_rmse(model, gX_test, gY_test, scaler, start_point, EV_data, n_train)

return RMSE, predictions
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined
```

Comment: The example code does not appear to be indented properly. Indentation is part of the syntax of Python. It's not optional.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please show the full traceback too

Comment: `get_rmse` apparently only returns one value, not 2 - so `predictions` is not defined.

Comment: @DanielleM. you'd get a different error in that case, something like `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object` or `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should be inside your function definition block.  I tried this and it compiled correctly:

```
def workflow(EV_data, get_split, train_model, get_rmse,n_train = 250,n_test = 50,look_back = 1):
    gX_train, gY_train, gX_test, gY_test, scaler, start_point = get_split(EV_data, n_train, n_test)

    model = train_model(gX_train, gY_train, gX_test, gY_test)

    RMSE, predictions = get_rmse(model, gX_test, gY_test, scaler, start_point, EV_data, n_train)

    return RMSE, predictions
```

Comment: Oh my god.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you.